# My tweak isn't doing anything, but I'm not getting any errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, tweak

I'm creating a tweak to change the colors of labels, status bar, control centre highlight color, and other text.
My code, when being built and compiled, gives no errors, but it isn't doing anything when I change the colors. Also, a bonus thing, I want to make a 'Respring!' button. 
Here is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

static BOOL enabled = YES;
static BOOL lsSame = YES;
static int labels = 0;
static int other = 13;
static int fg = 0;
static int bg = 13;
static int cc = 0;

/*
static UIColor *colorFromHexString(NSString *hexString) {
unsigned rgbValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
if ([hexString hasPrefix:@"#"]) {
[scanner setScanLocation:1];
} else {
[scanner setScanLocation:0];
}
[scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

static UIColor *colorFromRGB(int colorR, int colorG, int colorB) {
return [UIColor colorWithRed: colorR/255.0 green: colorG/255.0 blue: colorB/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
*/

%hook UILabel

-(void) setTextColor:(id)arg1 labels:(id)arg2 {
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.jordanmckee.customcolr.plist"];
if (settings) {
enabled = ([settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue] : enabled);
labels = ([settings objectForKey:@"labels"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"labels"] intValue] : labels);

switch (labels) {
case 1:
labels =[UIColor blackColor];
break;
case 2:
labels = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
break;
case 3:
labels = [UIColor grayColor];
break;
case 4:
labels =[UIColor lightGrayColor];
break;
case 5:
labels = [UIColor whiteColor];
break;
case 6:
labels = [UIColor redColor];
break;
case 7:
labels = [UIColor greenColor];
break;
case 8:
labels = [UIColor blueColor];
break;
case 9:
labels = [UIColor cyanColor];
break;
case 10:
labels = [UIColor magentaColor];
break;
case 11:
labels = [UIColor purpleColor];
break;
case 12:
labels = [UIColor orangeColor];
break;
case 13:
labels = [UIColor yellowColor];
break;
case 14:
labels = [UIColor clearColor];
default:
break;
}

if (enabled) {
return %orig(arg1,arg2);
}
return %orig;
}
}

%end

%hook _UICascadingTextstorage

-(void) setTextColor:(id)arg1 other:(id)arg2 {
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.jordanmckee.customcolr.plist"];
if (settings) {
enabled = ([settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue] : enabled);
other = ([settings objectForKey:@"other"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"other"] intValue] : other);

switch (other) {
case 1:
other = [UIColor blackColor];
break;
case 2:
other = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
break;
case 3:
other = [UIColor grayColor];
break;
case 4:
other = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
break;
case 5:
other = [UIColor whiteColor];
break;
case 6:
other = [UIColor redColor];
break;
case 7:
other = [UIColor greenColor];
break;
case 8:
other = [UIColor blueColor];
break;
case 9:
other = [UIColor cyanColor];
break;
case 10:
other = [UIColor magentaColor];
break;
case 11:
other = [UIColor purpleColor];
break;
case 12:
other = [UIColor orangeColor];
break;
case 13:
other = [UIColor yellowColor];
break;
case 14:
other = [UIColor clearColor];
default:
break;
}

if (enabled) {
return %orig(arg1,arg2);
}
return %orig;
}
}

%end

%hook UIStatusBarNewUIStyleAttributes

-(void)initWithRequest:(id)arg1 backgroundColor:(id)arg2 foregroundColor:(id)arg3 {
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.jordanmckee.customcolr.plist"];
if (settings) {
enabled = ([settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue] : enabled);
fg = ([settings objectForKey:@"fg"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"fg"] intValue] : fg);
bg = ([settings objectForKey:@"bg"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"bg"] intValue] : bg);

switch (fg) {
case 1:
fg = [UIColor blackColor];
break;
case 2:
fg = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
break;
case 3:
fg = [UIColor grayColor];
break;
case 4:
fg = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
break;
case 5:
fg = [UIColor whiteColor];
break;
case 6:
fg = [UIColor redColor];
break;
case 7:
fg = [UIColor greenColor];
break;
case 8:
fg = [UIColor blueColor];
break;
case 9:
fg = [UIColor cyanColor];
break;
case 10:
fg = [UIColor magentaColor];
break;
case 11:
fg = [UIColor purpleColor];
break;
case 12:
fg = [UIColor orangeColor];
break;
case 13:
fg = [UIColor yellowColor];
break;
case 14:
fg = [UIColor clearColor];
default:
break;
}

switch (bg) {
case 1:
bg = [UIColor blackColor];
break;
case 2:
bg = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
break;
case 3:
bg = [UIColor grayColor];
break;
case 4:
bg = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
break;
case 5:
bg = [UIColor whiteColor];
break;
case 6:
bg = [UIColor redColor];
break;
case 7:
bg = [UIColor greenColor];
break;
case 8:
bg = [UIColor blueColor];
break;
case 9:
bg = [UIColor cyanColor];
break;
case 10:
bg = [UIColor magentaColor];
break;
case 11:
bg = [UIColor purpleColor];
break;
case 12:
bg = [UIColor orangeColor];
break;
case 13:
bg = [UIColor yellowColor];
break;
case 14:
bg = [UIColor clearColor];
default:
break;
}

if (enabled) {
return %orig(arg1,arg2,arg3);
}
return %orig;
}
}

%end

%hook SBLockScreenViewController

-(int)statusBarStyle {
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.jordanckee.customcolr.plist"];
if (settings) {
lsSame = ([settings objectForKey:@"lssame"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"lssame"] boolValue] : lsSame);
}
if (lsSame) {
return 0;
}
return %orig;
}

%end

%hook SBControlCenterSettings

-(void)setHighlightedColor:(id)arg1 cc:(id)arg2 {
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.jordanmckee.customcolr.plist"];
if (settings) {
enabled = ([settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue] : enabled);
cc = ([settings objectForKey:@"cc"] ? [[settings objectForKey:@"cc"] boolValue] : cc);


switch (cc) {
case 1:
cc = [UIColor blackColor];
break;
case 2:
cc = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
break;
case 3:
cc = [UIColor grayColor];
break;
case 4:
cc = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
break;
case 5:
cc = [UIColor whiteColor];
break;
case 6:
cc = [UIColor redColor];
break;
case 7:
cc = [UIColor greenColor];
break;
case 8:
cc = [UIColor blueColor];
break;
case 9:
cc = [UIColor cyanColor];
break;
case 10:
cc = [UIColor magentaColor];
break;
case 11:
cc = [UIColor purpleColor];
break;
case 12:
cc = [UIColor orangeColor];
break;
case 13:
cc = [UIColor yellowColor];
break;
case 14:
cc = [UIColor clearColor];
default:
break;
}

if (enabled) {
return %orig(arg1,arg2);
}
return %orig;
}
}

%end
```

Comment: Suggestion - learn about arrays. There's no point to such a big `switch` statement to get a color when you can simply put the colors in an array. And if you find you are copying the same code over and over, you need to consider putting that duplicate code into a method for reuse.